# Defined function doesn't plot correctly

Tags: plotting, functions, trigonometry, conditional

I have defined a function that produces a single negative impulse spanning `-b` to `-a` and a positive impulse spanning `a` to `b`, and gives `0` for all other values of `x` (for real `x`). I then adjust the function so that the area under each single impulse is always equal to `-1` or `1`. So:

```
f[x_] := If[x < -b, 0, If[-b <= x <= -a, 
 -((Cos[Pi*((x + (a + b)/2)/((b - a)/2))] + 1)/(b - a)), 
 If[-a < x < a, 0, If[a <= x <= b, (Cos[Pi*((x + (a + b)/2)/((b - a)/2))] + 1)/
    (b - a), 0]]]]
```

Here's a plot to show what I'm after:

```
Plot[{f[x] /. a -> 1 /. b -> 2}, {x, -3, 3}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

This pattern should hold true for all values of `a<b`, no? However, it seems to fail for some values of `a` and `b`, and for positive `x` (but only for positive `x`, despite the function being so obviously odd). For example

```
Plot[{f[x] /. a -> 0 /. b -> 1, f[x] /. a -> 1 /. b -> 3, 
f[x] /. a -> 2 /. b -> 5, f[x] /. a -> 3 /. b -> 7, 
f[x] /. a -> 4 /. b -> 9}, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

produces

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks to JM for the answer below. I'll mark it as answered shortly. But first, would you mid explaining why it didn't work the way I had it? Is the function itself in error, or is this a MMA issue?

Comment: Debugging is a bit more work; if you don't mind waiting a bit, I'll write an extension much later.

Comment: I don't mind waiting at all. Would prefer to get to the bottom of it if poss. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can judiciously combine `Haversine[]`, `Rescale[]`, and `Clip[]`:

```
twinpulse[x_, {a_, b_}] /; 0 <= a < b := 
    2 Sign[x] Haversine[Clip[Rescale[Abs[x], {a, b}, {0, 2 π}], {0, 2 π}]]/(b - a)

Plot[Table[twinpulse[x, sp], {sp, {{0, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 5}, {3, 7}, {4, 9}}}] // Evaluate,
     {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: pulses]

---

### How to invent a function

I'll go over through the thought process I had in coming up with this solution, and along the way point out what was the problem with the OP's solution.

Some prerequisites: recall that the [haversine](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Haversine.html) can be expressed as

$$\operatorname{hav}(x)=\frac{1-\cos x}{2}=\sin^2\frac{x}{2}$$

It is a $2\pi$-periodic function, so one can restrict attention to the interval $[0,2\pi]$:

```
Plot[Haversine[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image: haversine]

which is in the right shape for a pulse.

The OP gave two additional stipulations for the pulse: it should range over $[a,b]$, and it should have unit area. However, the haversine ranges over $[0,2\pi]$ naturally, so a change of variables is needed.

*Mathematica* has a built-in function, `Rescale[]`, which can remap one interval to another. For this situation, we want a function that remaps the given interval $[a,b]$ to the haversine's natural interval $[0,2\pi]$:

```
Rescale[x, {a, b}, {0, 2 π}] // Together // Factor
   2 π (a - x)/(a - b)
```

which can now be composed with the haversine:

```
Haversine[Rescale[x, {a, b}, {0, 2 π}] // Factor] // FunctionExpand
   (1 - Cos[(2 π (a - x))/(a - b)])/2
```

At once, we spot a difference between this and the OP's expression: the OP's expression uses $1+\cos(\cdot)$, and a different shift $(a+b)/2$.

From here, we also need to impose the unit area constraint. That means we have to divide by the function by its integral over $[a,b]$:

```
Assuming[a < b, Integrate[(1 - Cos[(2 π (a - x))/(a - b)])/2, {x, a, b}]]
   (-a + b)/2
```

We're almost there! Now, the OP only wanted a single pulse, while haversine is actually a periodic function. Conveniently, haversine is zero at both ends of the interval, so we just need to add a `Clip[]` to restrict the result of `Rescale[]` before it gets passed to the haversine:

```
2 Haversine[Clip[Rescale[x, {a, b}, {0, 2 π}], {0, 2 π}]]/(b - a)
```

This shows only one pulse, so we need one last transformation. We replace `x` with `Abs[x]` and multiply by `Sign[x]`, which enforces the odd function condition. We finally have

```
2 Sign[x] Haversine[Clip[Rescale[Abs[x], {a, b}, {0, 2 π}], {0, 2 π}]]/(b - a)
```

which was the expression I used above.

Expressed more conventionally,

```
Assuming[x ∈ Reals && 0 <= a < b, 
         FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[PiecewiseExpand[
         2 Sign[x] Haversine[Clip[Rescale[Abs[x], {a, b}, {0, 2 π}], {0, 2 π}]]/(b - a)]]]]
```

$$\begin{cases}
 -\frac{2 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  (a-x)}{a-b}\right)}{a-b} & x>0\land 0\leq \frac{\pi  (a-x)}{a-b}\leq \pi  \\
 \frac{2 \sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  (a+x)}{a-b}\right)}{a-b} & x<0\land 0\leq \frac{\pi  (a+x)}{a-b}\leq \pi 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is totally awesome, and now marked as answered. But can I ask: what did I do wrong in the first place? You have totally reconstructed the function for me, and I'm hugely grateful; but I'm still not clear why my version didn't work...

Comment: As I said: you has used $1+\cos(\cdot)$ instead of haversine's $1-\cos(\cdot)$, and you had used the wrong shift of variable `x + (a + b)/2`.

Comment: Hmmm... OK, will have to think about that. Not clear to me why haversine is the way to go. But your solution works, and I'm very grateful.

Comment: If you really want to use $1+\cos$, then you need to rescale $[a,b]$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$: spot the difference between the result of `Rescale[x, {a, b}, {-π, π}]` and what you used in your formula.

Comment: OK, getting there now. Much appreciated.